# Diophantine matrix equation - Solver or algorithm

Tags: matrix-analysis

I look for a solver or reference rather than an answer about how to solve the diophantine matrix equation. One states it below.

$\mathbf{X}\mathbf{N} + \mathbf{Y}\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{I}$

All entries of X, N, Y and D belongs to polynomials. Therefore, it is cumbersome to achieve.

I thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solving that system is of course equivalent to solving
$$\begin{pmatrix}X & Y\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}N \\ D\end{pmatrix} = I$$

For examples of algorithms commonly used in computer algebra systems to solve such a system over the integers, look at:

J. D. Dixon.  Exact solution of linear equations using p-adic expansion. Numerische Mathematik, 40:137–141, 1982.

T.W.J. Chou and G.E. Collins., Algorithms for the solution of systems of linear Diophantine equations, SIAM J. Computing, 11(4):687--708, 1982.

Comment: I thank for the answer, but X, Y, N and D in my application os over the polynomial matrix ring. Specifically, I am more interested in any open source tool to obtain such matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by “polynomial matrix ring”? Can you state your problem more clearly and give some context?